# InternetCrackUrlW does not fill the values of strings behind pointers in structured class

Tags: python, ctypes, wininet

I am trying to parse a url using the [InternetCrackUrl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384376%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function from the WinINet library.

The "return" value of this function is done via the lpUrlComponents parameter which has a [defined structure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385420%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

The problem I now have is that my structured class only retrieves values in the numeric fields, `DWORD` and `INT`, but all the alphanumeric fields / all pointers, `LPCWSTR`, are empty (output at the end of the codeblock).

*I am aware the parameters in question should be pointers to the variable. I think that is the part that is wrong.*

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:** I added the few lines that were necesary to make it work at the end of the code block. This has been tested on Win8.1 and on XP.

```
from ctypes import *
from ctypes.wintypes import *

dll = windll.wininet

url = LPCWSTR("http://user:password@www.host.com:8080/url-path?key=value")
url_length = DWORD(len(url.value))
flags = DWORD()

class URL_COMPONENTS(Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ("dwStructSize", DWORD),
        ("lpszScheme", LPCWSTR),
        ("dwSchemeLength", DWORD),
        ("nScheme", INT),
        ("lpszHostName", LPCWSTR),
        ("dwHostNameLength", DWORD),
        ("nPort", INT),
        ("lpszUserName", LPCWSTR),
        ("dwUserNameLength", DWORD),
        ("lpszPassword", LPCWSTR),
        ("dwPasswordLength", DWORD),
        ("lpszUrlPath", LPCWSTR),
        ("dwUrlPathLength", DWORD),
        ("lpszExtraInfo", LPCWSTR),
        ("dwExtraInfoLength", DWORD),
    ]

url = LPCWSTR("http://user:password@www.host.com:8080/url-path?key=value")
url_length = DWORD(len(url.value))
flags = DWORD()
url_components = URL_COMPONENTS()

dll.InternetCrackUrlW.restype = c_bool

print "Output of initial question:"
print dll.InternetCrackUrlW(url, url_length, flags, byref(url_components))

for field in url_components._fields_:
     print field[0], getattr(url_components, field[0])

print "\nOutput of working:"

# Give the those lengths a nonzero value. == 0 do nothing, != 0 do something
url_components.dwHostNameLength = DWORD(-1)

dll.InternetCrackUrlW(url, url_length, flags, byref(url_components))

# Now we got the  string cut off at the start of the desired element.
print "lpszHostName:", url_components.lpszHostName

# And the length of the content.
print "dwHostNameLength:", url_components.dwHostNameLength

# Just cut it out and you get the desired result.
print "HostName:", url_components.lpszHostName[:url_components.dwHostNameLength]

Output of initial question output:
True
dwStructSize 60
lpszScheme None
dwSchemeLength 0
nScheme 3
lpszHostName None
dwHostNameLength 0
nPort 8080
lpszUserName None
dwUserNameLength 0
lpszPassword None
dwPasswordLength 0
lpszUrlPath None
dwUrlPathLength 0
lpszExtraInfo None
dwExtraInfoLength 0

Output of working:
lpszHostName: www.host.com:8080/url-path?key=value
dwHostNameLength: 12
HostName: www.host.com
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an implementation of the `URL_COMPONENTS` struct that sets all of the string buffers to a fixed size, defaulting to 512 characters.

```python
from ctypes import *
from ctypes.wintypes import *

wininet = WinDLL('wininet', use_last_error=True)

class URL_COMPONENTS(Structure):
    _fields_ = (("dwStructSize", DWORD),
                ("lpszScheme", LPWSTR),
                ("dwSchemeLength", DWORD),
                ("nScheme", INT),
                ("lpszHostName", LPWSTR),
                ("dwHostNameLength", DWORD),
                ("nPort", INT),
                ("lpszUserName", LPWSTR),
                ("dwUserNameLength", DWORD),
                ("lpszPassword", LPWSTR),
                ("dwPasswordLength", DWORD),
                ("lpszUrlPath", LPWSTR),
                ("dwUrlPathLength", DWORD),
                ("lpszExtraInfo", LPWSTR),
                ("dwExtraInfoLength", DWORD))
    def __init__(self, bufsize=512):
        self.dwStructSize = sizeof(self)
        fields = iter(self._fields_)
        for name, dtype in fields:
            if dtype == LPWSTR:
                buf = (c_wchar * bufsize)()
                setattr(self, name, cast(buf, LPWSTR))
                name, dtype = next(fields)
                setattr(self, name, bufsize)
```

```python
if __name__ == '__main__':
    url = LPCWSTR("http://user:password@www.host.com:8080/url-path?key=value")
    url_length = len(url.value)
    flags = 0
    url_components = URL_COMPONENTS()
    if not wininet.InternetCrackUrlW(url, url_length, flags,
                                     byref(url_components)):
        raise WinError(get_last_error())
    for name, dtype in url_components._fields_:
        print '%s: %s' % (name, getattr(url_components, name))
```

**Output:**

```
dwStructSize: 104
lpszScheme: http
dwSchemeLength: 4
nScheme: 3
lpszHostName: www.host.com
dwHostNameLength: 12
nPort: 8080
lpszUserName: user
dwUserNameLength: 4
lpszPassword: password
dwPasswordLength: 8
lpszUrlPath: /url-path
dwUrlPathLength: 9
lpszExtraInfo: ?key=value
dwExtraInfoLength: 10
```

Comment: Does that use the buffers you provide, or does it overwrite them with pointers into the url passed in?

Comment: @MarkJansen, it's using the buffers passed to it, per the docs: "If the pointer contains the address of the user-supplied buffer, the length member must contain the size of the buffer. `InternetCrackUrl` copies the component into the buffer, and the length member is set to the length of the copied component, minus 1 for the trailing string terminator".

Answer (score 1):

According to the [`remarks`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384376(v=vs.85).aspx):

> The required components are indicated by members of the `URL_COMPONENTS` structure. Each component has a pointer to the value and has a member that stores the length of the stored value. **If both the value and the length for a component are equal to zero, that component is not returned.**

So set the length component for all items you are interested in before calling `InternetCrackUrl`.

When the function returns, the pointers will be set for the valid components, but **they point to your own string!** Use both the pointer **and** the length to retrieve them from the structure.

Comment: Ok, so I tried a few things but I can't figured it out.

Comment: Sorry, I accidently hit Enter...
Does the length matter or can I just insert 1?
And then I have to read the the strings from the start to the position indicated by the length?

Comment: This works for me in Windows 7, and is generally more flexible and efficient than allocating buffers for each component. However, I was wary of the remarks in the [`InternetCrackUrl`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384376) docs that this behavior is only for Vista+. There are still a lot of XP users. I don't have an XP box/VM to test this.

Comment: Good point! I just tried it on XP (latest udpates installed) and it seems to work. The following is the output from the machine.
dwStructSize: 60
lpszScheme: http
dwSchemeLength: 4
nScheme: 3
lpszHostName: www.host.com
dwHostNameLength: 12
nPort: 8080
lpszUserName: user
dwUserNameLength: 4
lpszPassword: password
dwPasswordLength: 8
lpszUrlPath: /url-path
dwUrlPathLength: 9
lpszExtraInfo: ?key=value
dwExtraInfoLength: 10

Comment: @WaltheRed, was that result based on my answer that allocates string buffers, or Mark's (i.e.  set a non-zero size for each string, but leave the initial pointer as `NULL`)? In the latter case, it  sets the pointers to point into the url string that you passed as `lpszUrl`, so keep a reference and use the corresponding Length field to get the valid substring.

Comment: @eryksun, this war your example I ran on XP. I will try the described approcach aswell.